# Removing a Space With .strip() Not Working

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I have this homework assignment I am working on. I have everything working except the part to remove the spaces. I put the .strip() code at the end of the input line but it's not working. It still outputs Allen with a space in front of it when the input is Jill, Allen. Help!

MY CODE:

```
string = input('Enter input string: \n').strip()

while string:
    if string == 'q':
        break
    elif ',' in string:
        words = string.split(',')
        first_word = words[0]
        second_word = words[1]
        print('First Word:', first_word)
        print('Second Word:', second_word)
        break
    else:
        print('Error: No comma in string.')

    string = input('Enter input string: \n').strip()
```

MY ASSIGNMENT:

**Prompt the user for a string that contains two strings separated by a comma.**

Examples of strings that can be accepted:

Jill, Allen

Jill , Allen

Jill,Allen
Ex:

Enter input string: Jill, Allen

**Report an error if the input string does not contain a comma. Continue to prompt until a valid string is entered. Note: If the input contains a comma, then assume that the input also contains two strings.**

Ex:

Enter input string: Jill Allen

Error: No comma in string.

Enter input string: Jill, Allen

**Using string splitting, extract the two words from the input string and then remove any spaces. Output the two words.**

Ex:

Enter input string: Jill, Allen

First word: Jill

Second word: Allen

**Using a loop, extend the program to handle multiple lines of input. Continue until the user enters q to quit.**

Ex:

Enter input string: Jill, Allen

First word: Jill

Second word: Allen

Enter input string: Golden , Monkey

First word: Golden

Second word: Monkey

Enter input string: Washington,DC

First word: Washington

Second word: DC

Enter input string: q

Comment: You need `first_word.strip()` and `second_word.strip()`. Point to note here is `strip` removes only from ends and thus just the `strip` on input does not work.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, don;t name a variable `string`, it shadows the built-in [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module, which is a recipe for headaches down the road

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to the split tokens:

```
first_word = words[0].strip()
second_word = words[1].strip()
print('First Word: ', first_word)
print('Second Word: ', second_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.strip()` for the first time, you're removing the leading and trailing spaces for the whole input string.

So if `input()` gets the string `" Jill, Allen "` (which has three spaces – at position 0, position 6, and position 12), then when you call `.strip()` on that string, it removes the first and last space (positions 0 and 12) but keeps the middle space (position 6) and returns the string `"Jill, Allen"`.

Once you split on commas, python will split that string into `["Jill", " Allen"]`. You could split on a comma and a space (`", "`) but it would be better to split on the commas and then call `.strip()` on both of the names. For example:

```py
string = input('Enter input string: \n').strip()
#...
words = string.split(',')
first_word = words[0].strip()
second_word = words[1].strip()

print(" " in first_word)  # False
print(" " in second_word) # False
```

Hopefully that helps!